# How to combine 2 arrays into single one?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, as you will see bellow, and I want theme to combine into a single one. First 2 arrays have sub-arrays with a sum and a month. The result array(3rd), must have the sum of first 2 arrays for the same month.

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "sum" => 179.0
    "month" => "2016-01"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "sum" => 34.0
    "month" => "2016-02"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "sum" => 67.0
    "month" => "2016-03"
  ]
]


array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "sum" => 143.25
    "month" => "2016-01"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "sum" => 479.0
    "month" => "2016-03"
  ]
]


Total:

array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "sum" => 313.25
    "month" => "2016-01"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "sum" => 34.0
    "month" => "2016-02"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "sum" => 546.0
    "month" => "2016-03"
  ]
]
```

What I tried:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($com1);$i++){
            for ($j=0; $j < count($com2); $j++) { 
                if($com1[$i]['month'] == $com2[$j]['month']){
                    $total = $com1[$i]['sum']+$com2[$j]['sum']
                }
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't give the result I want

I am abit noob...I hope someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$com1 = [
  0 => [
    'sum' => 179.0,
    'month' => '2016-01'
  ],
  1 => [
    'sum' => 34.0,
    'month' => '2016-02'
  ],
  2 => [
    'sum' => 67.0,
    'month' => '2016-03'
  ]
];

$com2 = [
  0 => [
    'sum' => 143.25,
    'month' => '2016-01'
  ],
  1 => [
    'sum' => 479.0,
    'month' => '2016-03'
  ]
];

$total = [];
foreach ($com1 as $data) {
    $total[$data['month']] = $data;
}

foreach ($com2 as $data) {
    if (!isset($total[$data['month']])) {
        $total[$data['month']] = [
            'sum' => 0,
            'month' => $data['month']
        ];
    }
    $total[$data['month']]['sum'] += $data['sum'];
}

print_r($total);
```

Comment: I can't help but notice that here the output array is an associative array, while a sequential array was requested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that generates a non-associative array (as you indicated in your question):

```
$month_idx = []; // helper to identify at which index a certain month is stored
$result = [];
foreach (array_merge($data1, $data2) as $idx => $row) {
    $month = $row["month"];
    if (!isset($month_idx[$month])) {
        $month_idx[$month] = count($result);
        $result[] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$month_idx[$month]]["sum"] += $row["sum"];
    }
}

var_export($result);
```

When $data1 and $data2 are:

```
$data1 = array (
    array(
        "sum" => 179.0,
        "month" => "2016-01"
    ),
    array(
        "sum" => 34.0,
        "month" => "2016-02"
    ),
    array(
        "sum" => 67.0,
        "month" => "2016-03"
    )
);
$data2 = array (
    array(
        "sum" => 143.25,
        "month" => "2016-01"
    ),
    array(
        "sum" => 479.0,
        "month" => "2016-03"
    )
);
```

Then output is:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'sum' => 322.25,
    'month' => '2016-01',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'sum' => 34,
    'month' => '2016-02',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'sum' => 546,
    'month' => '2016-03',
  ),
)
```